# Having difficulty in interpreting a line code in c++

Tags: c++

I am having difficulty in understanding this line in c++. 
This is the code :

`cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr_depth (new cv_bridge::CvImage);`

I think that `cv_bridge` is a library and `CvImagePtr` is the name of a class in that library, but what is `cv_ptr_depth`? Is it a function? If I am right, does the `(new cv_bridge::CvImage)` create a new `CvImage` object for the function `cv_ptr_depth` of the class `cv_bridge`?

Comment: It's a variable. This is just a variable declaration. `cv_ptr_depth` is initialized with a new `CvImage` instance as its constructor's parameter.

Comment: Learning the basics should be much easier from a good book (see the tag's page) than from answers here.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant it's very close to being prone to [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Without the `new` in there it almost certainly would.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cv_ptr_depth` is a variable of type `CvImagePtr` present in namespace `cv_bridge` initialized with a new instance of `CvImage` which is gain from `cv_bridge` namespace

The initialization is done with help of constructor of `CvImagePtr`

> Is it a function ?

No, however if you omit `new` it will be treated as a function.

See [*Most Vexing Parse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)